# How do I activate a VSCode environment from ssh?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, vscode-remote

I am currently using VS Code on a server (through SSH). Everything works fine, and I installed Python packages and work with Python notebooks.

Now, I want to login to the server (not a problem) and run the Python code I created on VSCode, rather than executing it remotely.

My main issue is that I am not sure how to activate the Python environment (if there is one) that VSCode server's run so that the code can execute.

Is that possible?

I see I have a .vscode directory in my home directory, and there are package installation there.

Answer (score 0):

After connecting vscode remotely, you can use it as a regular vscode, which is no different from running Python files locally:

1. install **python**
2. install **pylance extension**
3. choose correct interpreter
4. edit your code and run the python file.

Comment: sorry, I am not sure I understand your answer.

Comment: Tell more details about the server you connect to remotely. Has it installed Python and Python extensions invscode? After the SSH connection is successful, there is no difference between using everything and using vscode locally.